# how to prevent safari from caching an svg

Tags: caching, svg, safari

On my server I have a php script, which updates logo.svg every minute (at the moment only a color change, later on more).

In firefox the logo.svg is shown properly (a new color every minute), but in Safari I have to manually clear the cache to get the new versions.

I tried to fix it with a .htaccess entry but it's not working.

htaccess:

```
 <IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 0 seconds"
 </IfModule>
```

svg header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 15.0.2, SVG Export Plug-In  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd" [
    <!ENTITY ns_flows "http://ns.adobe.com/Flows/1.0/">
]>
<svg version="1.1"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:a="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeSVGViewerExtensions/3.0/"
     x="0px" y="0px" width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 200 200" overflow="visible" enable-background="new 0 0 200 200"
     xml:space="preserve">
<defs>
</defs>
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>

<div id="header">
    <a href="../">
        <div id="logo">
        </div>
    </a> 
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
<style>#logo{background-image: url(/g/logo.svg);}</style>
```

Comment: Does your .htaccess file contain an `ExpiresActive On` directive?

Comment: As a last resort you could append a timestamp to the end of the svg url, `background-image: url(/g/logo.svg?1234453)`;

Comment: thx for this option, but i'd rather not do that. the #logo definition is in a separate css file, and i'd like to keep this structure